# Dask: data conversion netcdf -> netcdf which is larger than available memory

Tags: dask, python-xarray, netcdf, large-data

I'm trying to convert some model output (a series of time series) back into a georeferenced grid. I have the output time series as a NetCDF and the mask of which time series corresponds to which grid cell. As long as the output array does fit into memory, it is very fast when using Numba (I know, that a double loop is not pythonic - numba+loops was the way to get it quickly working). Because it can easily exceed the available memory, I'd like to retool it using Dask + delayed array so that the computation is written directly to the output NetCDF.

From what I gather, the problem is the double loop, see the code below - it needs to be rewritten so that the computation is delayed until output. How do I do that?

Thanks for your help!

```
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np
import rioxarray
import xarray as xr

# load the mask + location
rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(
    file_mask_description
)

# load the result timeseries
res = xr.open_dataset(
    '1950-01-01.nc',
    group='data',
    chunks={"time": 8760},
    decode_times=True)

# explicit time array
time_start = "1950-01-01T00:00:00.0"
timings = np.array([
        np.datetime64(time_start, 'ns') + x * np.timedelta64(1, "h")
        for x in res['time'].values
    ])

num_timesteps = len(timings)

# determine chunksize - ~1GB sounds good
# always creates at least two
chunk_size = (min(
    int(round(num_timesteps / 2)),
    int(round(1000000000 / (rds.data.shape[1] * rds.data.shape[2])))),
              rds.data.shape[1], rds.data.shape[2])

# setup the delayed array
output_data = xr.Dataset(
    coords={
        "x": rds.coords['x'],
        "y": rds.coords['y'],
        "time": timings
    },
    data_vars={
        "smc1": (
            ["time", "y", "x"],
            da.full_like(
                (num_timesteps, rds.data.shape[1], rds.data.shape[2]),
                -9999.0,
                chunks=chunk_size,
                dtype="float32",
                shape=(num_timesteps, rds.data.shape[1], rds.data.shape[2])),
        )
    },
    attrs={
        "_FillValue": -9999.0,
        "units": res['smc1'].units,
        "description": res['smc1'].description
    },
)

# fill output array
# this is fast when run through Numba
# but forces the computation of the delayed array
hrus_int = rds.data.astype(np.int16)
for i in range(0, hrus_int.shape[1]):
    for j in range(0, hrus_int.shape[2]):

        if hrus_int[0, i, j] != -9999.0:
            output_data["smc1"][:, i, j] = res['smc1'][:, hrus_int[0, i, j]]

# export data
output_data.to_netcdf("saved_on_disk.nc")
```

Comment: The approach of creating an empty Dask Array and filling it is not a correct one. Ideally if you can you should build it from the input array using map_blocks or similar.

Maybe you can also try to post to https://discourse.pangeo.io/.